# How to give the permissions to sql server 2008 database to insert the data from client system in c# windows application?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, permissions

How to give the **permissions to sql server 2008 database** to insert the data from client system in c# windows application(**I am able to fetch the data from database in remote server but i am unable to insert the data from client system to remote server database**)

Comment: What permissions have you give the sql server login specified in the connection string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a user in `SQL server 2008` database having rights to insert data, and use that user's credentials in your `connection string`.

Comment: i want to use sql server default login "sa" , if any permissions add to that login pls give me some idea about that